# Sharing data between android fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, android-checkbox

I have two fragments.
The **checkNodesFragment** creates dynamically an ArrayList of checkBoxes and then 
the **ReserveNodesFragment** should access which of them were checked in checkNodesFragment.
What storage method is better to use, so as ReserveNodesFragment can see what checkBoxes where checked?

After searching, i found that **SharedPreferences** is a method to store data permanently. Is SharedPreferences suitable for making data visible through fragments?
I am newbie in android, so sorry if the question is obvious.

Comment: Are these fragments used together within Activity? In other words, are you trying to just transfer data from one fragment to another in runtime and you don't have to store it permanently?

Comment: If those fragments are used in same Activity, why not make this ArrayList belong to that Activity?

SharedPreferences is a data storage method. It relies on saving the date in a file. So it's suitable wherever you want on your application. But SharedPref use is more desirable for storing data and retrieving them even if your application is closed.

Comment: you can try a basic bean with static variable and methods (single ton) simple one.

Comment: Singleton? Do you mean  to define a class
public class GlobalData extends Application{
and declare in AndroidManifest.xml that is a class containing global data. So all data that i share would be global?
I am trying to find the most elegant solution since i have six categories of checkBoxes.
I have six categories of dynamic ArrayList checkBoxes:
orbitCheckBoxes, icarusCheckBoxes, baseStationCheckBoxes e.t.c.
and the ReserveNodesFragment should see which checkBoxes are checked. So i should store the checkboxes status in six categories.

Answer (score 2):

**The communication between fragments should be done via `Activity`.**

**Sharing Data between `Activity` to `Fragment`**

Create a bundle and use `fragment.setArguments(bundle)` to pass data to `Fragment`.

**Sharing Data between `Fragment` to `Activity`**

create an `interface` in your `fragment` and in your `Activity` implement the `interface`

More info:

[**Communicating with Other Fragments**](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) (Download the sample).

Comment: Can we pass data between two fragments without an activity? I have parent fragment in which there are two child fragments and i need to pass data between two child fragments.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to transfer data across fragments in runtime you can simply use Activity.

Every fragment has method `getActivity()`. It's a kind of parent for your fragments so you can use it as a "bridge". Nice solution would be defining callbacks in your fragments. Then your Activity could be working as registered observer for these callbacks and react accordingly e.g. listen for changes in the first fragment and then set something on the second fragment.

In more details.

1. Define `interface` in your fragment that provides information about changes. Create method that will be called in fragment when checkbox is selected.
2. In `onAttach()` method check if `getActivity()` is instance of that `interface`
3. Make you Activity to implement that `interface`
4. Implement method in Activity. Inside that method call second fragment and pass updated information.

Nice example can be found when you create an Activity from a template with fragment in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned, i have two fragments.  **checkNodesFragment** creates dynamically an ArrayList of checkBoxes and then the **ReserveNodesFragment** should access which of them were checked in **checkNodesFragment** .
But i have six Arraylists of checkBoxes that ReserveNodesFragment should know:

```
//The ArrayLists with the checkBoxes
    public ArrayList<CheckBox> orbitCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
    public ArrayList<CheckBox> gridCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
    public ArrayList<CheckBox> usrpCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
    public ArrayList<CheckBox> disklessCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
    public ArrayList<CheckBox> icarusCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
    public ArrayList<CheckBox> baseStationsCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
```

So according to your suggestion i should pass six parameters to the method of the interface, so as ReserveNodesFragment will have access to the six ArrayLists:

```
// Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        public void onReserveSelected(ArrayList<CheckBox> orbitCheckBoxes, ArrayList<CheckBox> gridCheckBoxes, ArrayList<CheckBox> usrpCheckBoxes, ArrayList<CheckBox> disklessCheckBoxes,
                                      ArrayList<CheckBox> icarusCheckBoxes,  ArrayList<CheckBox> baseStationsCheckBoxes);
    }
```

*So it is elegant to pass so many parameters to the callback method?*

Also, the **checkNodesFragment** is  a **nested** fragment to the AvailableNodesFragment. So its parent is not an activity but a Fragment.

So the app hierarchy is like this:

NitosSchedulerActivity --> AvailableNodesFragment-->CheckAvailableNodesFragment

NitosSchedulerActivity --> ReserveNodesFragment

The CheckAvailableNodesFragment is a nested Fragment to AvailableNodesFragment.

The ReserveNodesFragment is triggered by a Button of the AvailableNodesFragment.
So, there is not a way to trigger a callback method from CheckAvailableNodesFragment to
ReserveNodesFragment  for passing the ArrayLists.

So, until now the only way i found to make the ArrayLists of CheckBoxes visible to the **ReserveNodesFragment** is to make the ArrayLists declared globally.

However, making ArrayLists global is an elegant solution?