# How to get value from one fragment and pass to another fragment

Tags: java, android

I have two fragment, one is Fragment X and Fragment y.. Fragment X is used for signup process using webservice. I want to pass(email,mobile) same value from Fragment X to Fragment Y.

Here my code:

Fragment x:

```js
Signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String sName = Name.getText().toString();
                    String sPhoneNo = Phone.getText().toString();
                    String sEmailId = EmailId.getText().toString();



                    // Instantiate Http Request Param Object
                    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

                    if (Utility.isNotNull(sName) && Utility.isNotNull(sPhoneNo) && Utility.isNotNull(sEmailId) ) {
                        if (Utility.line2_validate(sName)) {
                            if (Utility.validate(sPhoneNo)) {
                                if (Utility.email_validate(sEmailId)) {

                                   //Get value from this Fragment 
                                    FragmentY pf = new FragmentY ();
                                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                                    args.putString("mobile", sPhoneNo);
                                    args.putString("email",sEmailId);
                                    pf.setArguments(args);

                                    //Inflate the fragment
                                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.passwordLayout, pf).commit();

                                    // Put Http parameter username with value of Name Edit View control
                                    params.put("name", sName);
                                    // Put Http parameter email with value of Email Edit Value control
                                    params.put("email", sEmailId);
                                    // Put Http parameter mobile with value of Mobile Edit Value control
                                    params.put("mobile", sPhoneNo);
                                    // Invoke Signup RESTful Web Service with Http parameters
                                    signUpWS(params);

                                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    //((MainActivity) getActivity()).navigatetoPasswordActivity();

                                }
                                else {
                                    EmailId.setError("Enter valid Email");
                                }

                            }
                            else {
                                Phone.setError("Enter valid Mobile");
                            }

                        }
                        else {
                            Name.setError("Enter valid Name");
                        }

                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Please fill the form, don't leave any field blank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }



            });
```

Fragment Y:

```js
//  Retrive the value from fragment x
String strMobile = getArguments().getString("mobile");
                String strEmail = getArguments().getString("email");
```

Please anyone help me..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't get the problem, you have your Fragment-Object as `pf`. Why don't you simply set 2 parameters on that object?

Comment: I dont know what to do.. Help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194548/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445594/data-sharing-between-fragments-and-activity-in-android
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062879/sharing-data-between-android-fragments

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081101/using-localbroadcastmanager-to-communicate-from-fragment-to-activity/24083101#24083101

Answer (score 1):

You can pass value to fargment by creating constructor in fragment

For Example,

**for fragment x** pass value in constructor

```
PasswordFragment pf = new PasswordFragment (name, email, mobile);
```

**for fragmnet y** you can retrive value from this constructor

```
String name, email, mobile
public PasswordFragment(String name, String email, String mobile) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.name=name;
        this.email=email;
        this.mobile=mobile;
}
```

Comment: That one line is enough for fragment x

Comment: Where can i put this line?

Comment: Instead of 
PasswordFragment pf = new PasswordFragment ();
write 
PasswordFragment pf = new PasswordFragment (name, email, mobile);

Answer (score 0):

I know that Fragment should communicate through the Activity they are attached to; a way to solve your problem would be to declare

```
final Activity activity = this.getActivity();
```

and use it to pass the values you need via Activity attributes (private or public that's your choice), like

```
String value1;
String value2; //Into Activity
```

than, once you filled them up, you can retrieve their value from FragmentY.

EDIT: of course, you will need a cast to YourCustomActivity when declaring the final Activity object in your Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to look into this.
 http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Its pretty clean and advisable.No fragments should communicate themselves directly.best approach is to use the calling activity as a mediator between both the fragments